# What am I doing wrong in this SQL Query?

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm new to if-then SQL statements. I only know the basics (select, update, insert with joins etc.), so it will be helpful if you could help me with the syntax in this scenario.

I have a table that holds customer's activities, let's say I'm a dentist, and I store a specific activity, and when using my software to check out what the customer should pay, I use this query:

```
SELECT ACTIVITY.ID, 
       ACTIVITY.DATES, 
       ACTIVITY.INSURANCE_ID 
       ACTIVITY.AMOUNT, 
       ACTIVITY.INSURANCE_AMOUNT, 
       ACTIVITY.AMOUNT * ((100 - ACTIVITY.INSURANCE_AMOUNT) / 100) AS AMOUNT_TO_PAY, 
       ACTIVITY.TIME, 
       ACTIVITY.MONEY_RECEIVED,
       ACTIVITY.ROWID
FROM ACTIVITY
LEFT JOIN INSURANCE ON INSURANCE.ID = ACTIVITY.INSURANCE_ID 
WHERE ACTIVITY.ID = :patient_id AND ACTIVITY.MONEY_RECEIVED IS NULL
```

This query selects the data I need plus the amount that the customer should pay, calculating the percentage discount from the insurance amount and returning the total amount to pay as money (AMOUNT_TO_PAY).

This works fine, but the problem is, this calculation happens even if the insurance is expired. I want to make a SQL statement with if-then or whatever other method in ORACLE JDEVELOPER, that first will check if my table CUSTOMER_INSURANCE.TO_DATE is still active; if it is, do the calculation; if the DATE is expired, do not include the insurance percentage.

Here is the query I'm trying to execute but I'm doing something wrong:

```
IF ((SELECT count(*) FROM CUSTOMER_INSURANCE.TO_DATE TO_DATE 
    WHERE TO_DATE >= sysdate AND customer_id = :patient_id) > 0)
SELECT ACTIVITY.ID, 
       ACTIVITY.DATES, 
       ACTIVITY.INSURANCE_ID 
       ACTIVITY.AMOUNT, 
       ACTIVITY.INSURANCE_AMOUNT, 
       ACTIVITY.AMOUNT * ((100 - ACTIVITY.INSURANCE_AMOUNT) / 100) AS AMOUNT_TO_PAY, 
       ACTIVITY.TIME, 
       ACTIVITY.MONEY_RECEIVED,
       ACTIVITY.ROWID
FROM ACTIVITY
LEFT JOIN INSURANCE ON INSURANCE.ID = ACTIVITY.INSURANCE_ID 
WHERE ACTIVITY.ID = :patient_id AND ACTIVITY.MONEY_RECEIVED IS NULL
ELSE IF ((SELECT count(*) FROM CUSTOMER_INSURANCE.TO_DATE TO_DATE 
    WHERE TO_DATE >= sysdate AND customer_id = :patient_id) = 0)
SELECT ACTIVITY.ID, 
       ACTIVITY.DATES, 
       ACTIVITY.INSURANCE_ID 
       ACTIVITY.AMOUNT, 
       ACTIVITY.INSURANCE_AMOUNT, 
       ACTIVITY.AMOUNT AS AMOUNT_TO_PAY, 
       ACTIVITY.TIME, 
       ACTIVITY.MONEY_RECEIVED,
       ACTIVITY.ROWID
FROM ACTIVITY
LEFT JOIN INSURANCE ON INSURANCE.ID = ACTIVITY.INSURANCE_ID 
WHERE ACTIVITY.ID = :patient_id AND ACTIVITY.MONEY_RECEIVED IS NULL
```

Can anyone help me finish this query?

Comment: There is not `IF` in Oracle SQL. If can only be used in PL/SQL inside a stored procedure/function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this should work. You can change the CASE based on your requirement.

```
select  ACTIVITY.ID, 
       ACTIVITY.DATES, 
       ACTIVITY.INSURANCE_ID 
       ACTIVITY.AMOUNT, 
       ACTIVITY.INSURANCE_AMOUNT,
       CASE WHEN  TO_DATE >= sysdate 
                THEN  ACTIVITY.AMOUNT * ((100 - ACTIVITY.INSURANCE_AMOUNT) / 100)
                WHEN TO_DATE < sysdate
                THEN  ACTIVITY.AMOUNT
                END AS AMOUNT_TO_PAY
FROM 
(
SELECT ACTIVITY.ID, 
       ACTIVITY.DATES, 
       ACTIVITY.INSURANCE_ID 
       ACTIVITY.AMOUNT, 
       ACTIVITY.INSURANCE_AMOUNT, 
       ACTIVITY.AMOUNT  
       ACTIVITY.TIME, 
       ACTIVITY.MONEY_RECEIVED,
       ACTIVITY.ROWID
FROM ACTIVITY
LEFT JOIN INSURANCE ON INSURANCE.ID = ACTIVITY.INSURANCE_ID 
WHERE ACTIVITY.ID = :patient_id AND ACTIVITY.MONEY_RECEIVED IS NULL
)
WHERE ACTIVITY.ID = :patient_id;
```

Thanks,
Aditya

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer, it worked perfectly, i just needed to add another join to remove the double rows. How do i mark this as an answer? cant find anywhere the button

Comment: Glad to know it worked for you. You can select the "This Answer is Useful button" on the left hand side of my response.

Answer (score 1):

You can add a CASE expression to return the `ACTIVITY.INSURANCE_AMOUNT` value conditionally:

```
SELECT ACTIVITY.ID, 
       ACTIVITY.DATES, 
       ACTIVITY.INSURANCE_ID 
       ACTIVITY.AMOUNT, 
       ACTIVITY.INSURANCE_AMOUNT, 
       ACTIVITY.AMOUNT * (1 - CASE
                                WHEN EXISTS (
                                  SELECT *
                                  FROM CUSTOMER_INSURANCE.TO_DATE
                                  WHERE TO_DATE >= sysdate
                                    AND customer_id = :patient_id
                                )
                                THEN ACTIVITY.INSURANCE_AMOUNT
                                ELSE 0
                              END / 100) AS AMOUNT_TO_PAY,
       ACTIVITY.TIME, 
       ACTIVITY.MONEY_RECEIVED,
       ACTIVITY.ROWID

FROM ACTIVITY

LEFT JOIN INSURANCE ON INSURANCE.ID = ACTIVITY.INSURANCE_ID 

WHERE ACTIVITY.ID = :patient_id AND ACTIVITY.MONEY_RECEIVED IS NULL
;
```

When there are matching rows in `CUSTOMER_INSURANCE.TO_DATE`, the `ACTIVITY.INSURANCE_AMOUNT` value is returned to calculate the remaining amount, otherwise 0 is returned and so the entire expression evaluates to just `ACTIVITY.AMOUNT`.

Notes:

1. The "percentage to pay" calculation was changed from `(100 - x) / 100` to the equivalent (and slightly shorter) `1 - x/100` form.
2. The `(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM ...) > 0` predicate was replaced with the possibly more efficient `EXISTS (SELECT * FROM ...)` one.

Answer (score 0):

```
 IF CUSTOMER_INSURANCE.TO_DATE >= GetDate()  THEN
  ACTIVITY.AMOUNT * ((100 - ACTIVITY.INSURANCE_AMOUNT) / 100);
   ELSE ACTIVITY.AMOUNT;
```

Would the previous statment work? Be warned this has not been tested.

Comment: My problem is, i don't know how to syntax that in my original sql query

Comment: Replace it with the line ACTIVITY.AMOUNT * ((100 - ACTIVITY.INSURANCE_AMOUNT) / 100); in your select statment

Comment: Like this? SELECT ACTIVITY.ID, 
       ACTIVITY.DATES, 
       ACTIVITY.INSURANCE_ID 
       ACTIVITY.AMOUNT, 
       ACTIVITY.INSURANCE_AMOUNT,
       IF CUSTOMER_INSURANCE.TO_DATE >= GetDate()  THEN
        ACTIVITY.AMOUNT * ((100 - ACTIVITY.INSURANCE_AMOUNT) / 100) AS AMOUNT_TO_PAY
         ELSE ACTIVITY.AMOUNT AS AMOUNT_TO_PAY
       ACTIVITY.TIME, 
       ACTIVITY.MONEY_RECEIVED,
       ACTIVITY.ROWID

FROM ACTIVITY

LEFT JOIN INSURANCE ON INSURANCE.ID = ACTIVITY.INSURANCE_ID 

WHERE ACTIVITY.ID = :patient_id AND ACTIVITY.MONEY_RECEIVED IS NULL

Comment: You can't use `IF` in an Oracle SQL statement.

Comment: In addition to what @a_horse_with_no_name said, you cannot reference `CUSTOMER_INSURANCE.TO_DATE` like that because it is a *table*, not a column. And it doesn't take part in the query at all, the IF condition in the OP's code merely checks whether that table has particular rows, nothing more.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Oracle then it is a bad practice to use the keyword TO_DATE or DATES, TIME as column alias which might throw an error. Also you do not need IF ELSE statement since this can be achieved in the normal UNION ALL.

```
SELECT
      ACTIVITY.ID,
      ACTIVITY.DATES,
      ACTIVITY.INSURANCE_ID,
      ACTIVITY.AMOUNT,
      ACTIVITY.INSURANCE_AMOUNT,
      CASE
          WHEN TO_DATE >= SYSDATE
          THEN
              ACTIVITY.AMOUNT
              * ( ( 100
                  - ACTIVITY.INSURANCE_AMOUNT )
                / 100 )
          ELSE
              ACTIVITY.AMOUNT
      END
          AS AMOUNT_TO_PAY,
      ACTIVITY.TIME,
      ACTIVITY.MONEY_RECEIVED,
      ACTIVITY.ROWID
FROM
      CUSTOMER_INSURANCE,
          ACTIVITY
      LEFT JOIN
          INSURANCE
      ON INSURANCE.ID = ACTIVITY.INSURANCE_ID
WHERE
         ACTIVITY.ID = :PATIENT_ID
      AND ACTIVITY.MONEY_RECEIVED IS NULL
      AND CUSTOMER_ID = :PATIENT_ID
```

Comment: This actualy make it even worse, it brings me the same 9 rows that calculates the amount_to_pay percentage with expired insurance AND calcutates the amount_to_pay percentage with active insurance. So thats total 18 rows.

Comment: Could you please try this? Also if you face any error, let me know the sample data set and sample result.

Comment: it bring me double rows, half with expired insurance and the other half with active insurance.

Comment: Could you please provide me sample rows for the tables and expected result? @PhilipManetas

Comment: The TO_DATE column belongs to an entirely different dataset, one that is not used in the join at all. The OP is merely checking whether that dataset has rows matching a condition, in order to decide how to obtain the `AMOUNT_TO_PAY` value.